# update an object with a new object

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic-framework

i have an array that is been already loaded on to view, i need to update a specific object in array

```
modified_data(){
        this.nativeStorage.getItem("modifiedData").then((data)=>{
            console.log("modified_data fun", data);
        //  console.log(this.dailyDays);
            var array = this.dailyDays;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var element = array[i];
            //  console.log("in aloop",element.day);
                if (element.day === data.day) {
                    console.log("got same da", element);
                    this.dailyDays.push({
                                    day: data.day,
                                    month: this.currentDate.getMonth(),
                                    year: this.currentDate.getFullYear(),
                                    price: data.price,
                                    brand: data.selectedBrand,
                                    howManyDay: data.selectedDay,
                                    quantity: data.selectedQuantity
                                });

                } else {

                }

            }
        })
}
```

By using the above code a new object gets added up at the bottom of the array in html,

The array in the view have a date listed if i find the same date then that date should be updated with the new object 
some one help me

Comment: Check if this post helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44121993/5556177

Comment: Please follow below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689856/how-to-change-value-of-object-which-is-inside-an-array-using-javascript-or-jquer

Comment: could you give direct solution i am confused @Nehal

Comment: Need little clarification first, so, you are trying compare `data` object with all objects in `array` and if you don't find a match, you add `data` to `array`, if you do find a match, you need to replace the existing one with `data`, correct?

Comment: ya exactly but i need only to update the array with new data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the logic should look something like this. It looks for an existing object in the `array`, if it finds a match, returns the `index`, if not, returns `-1`. Based on that, you can perform

```
modified_data(){
  this.nativeStorage.getItem("modifiedData").then((data)=>{
    console.log("modified_data fun", data);
    //  console.log(this.dailyDays);
    // var array = this.dailyDays;
    let updateItem = this.dailyDays.find(this.findIndexToUpdate, data.day); 

    let index = this.dailyDays.indexOf(updateItem); 

    if(index > -1){
      // Add whatever logic you need to update existing object
      // below line will replace the whole object
      this.dailyDays[index] = data;   
    }
    else{
      this.dailyDays.push({
         day: data.day,
         month: this.currentDate.getMonth(),
         year: this.currentDate.getFullYear(),
         price: data.price,
         brand: data.selectedBrand,
         howManyDay: data.selectedDay,
         quantity: data.selectedQuantity
      })
    }   
  })

findIndexToUpdate(data) { 
        return data.day === this;
}
```