# Angular subscribe to object property changes

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a service which holds some data:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  data = {
    a: [
      {label: 'label 1', checked: true},
      {label: 'label 2', checked: true},
      {label: 'label 3', checked: true}
    ]
  }
}
```

and a component that imports the service and uses data from `data.a` to generate checkboxes (with `checked` property indicating the initial state of each checkbox). After user checks and unchecks boxes, values in `DataService` are automatically updated by angular.

There is another service `StorageService` which also injects `DataService` and is supposed to store `data.a` to browser's local storage automatically every time a `checked` property is changed. What I can't figure out is how to observe those changes for individual object properties which are nested deeply like so?

Answer (score 0):

`a` is some array of something? Array, Interface?

In your service `StorageService` you can access data througt

```
constructor(private _dataService : DataService  ){}

console.log(this._dataService.data.a[0].label);
```

Post more some code if this not working for you.

Comment: `a` is just an array of objects. It's static data. I can access the data in `StorageService` but what I need it to do is to subscribe to it to detect any changes of data. I presume I should make `data` object observable (perhaps rxjs `BehaviorSubject`) but I can't figure out how to make it work on such object.

Comment: Then check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120645/angular-update-object-in-object-array