# How to update array of object from another object array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two object arrays. One is main array and another one is temp array. I need to compare main array with temp array and based on matching id, I have update the value in the main array from temp array.

For example, id 2 & 3 is matching in both the arrays. So I need to update value in the main array from temp array.

```
// Main array
this.MyArray = [
    { id: "0", value: "Car" },
    { id: "1", value: "Bike" },
    { id: "2", value: "Train" },
    { id: "3", value: "Bus" },
    { id: "4", value: "Van" }
]

// temp array
this.tempArray =[
    { id: "2", value: "Car" },
    { id: "3", value: "Jet" },
]

//Expected Output in the Main array:
this.MyArray = [
    { id: "0", value: "Car" },
    { id: "1", value: "Bike" },
    { id: "2", value: "Car" },
    { id: "3", value: "Jet" },
    { id: "4", value: "Van" }
]
```

Comment: You can just loop over the temp array following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120645/angular-update-object-in-object-array

I like even the second answer

Comment: @MarcoMassetti - In that example one is object and another one is object array but in my case both are array of objects.

Comment: `this.tempArray.ForEach(item =>{
    this.MyArray.find(myitem => myitem.id == item.id).name = item.name;
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Immutable option. Creating a new `Array` based on the `myArray` with updates from the `tempArray`:

```
this.myArray = this.myArray.map((mainObject) => {
  const tempObject = this.tempArray.find((tempObject) => tempObject.id === mainObject.id);

  if (typeof tempObject !== "undefined") {
    return {
       ...mainObject,
       value: tempObject.value,
    };
  }

  return mainObject;
});
```

2. Mutable option. Looping over the `tempArray` and replacing the objects in the `myArray` with the relevant object from the `tempArray`:

```
this.tempArray.forEach((tempObject) => {
  const mainObjectIndex = this.myArray.findIndex((mainObject) => mainObject.id === tempObject.id);

  if (mainObjectIndex !== -1) {
    this.myArray[mainObjectIndex] = tempObject;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To update `myArray` with values of `tempArray`, you can use the `reduce` operator, in order to do it in an immutable way :

```
tempArray.reduce((existingEntries, tempEntry) => {
      const duplicateEntry = existingEntries.find((entry) => entry.id === tempEntry.id)
      if (duplicateEntry && duplicateEntry.value !== tempEntry.value) {
        const duplicateIndex = existingEntries.indexOf(duplicateEntry)
        return [...existingEntries.slice(0, duplicateIndex), tempEntry, ...existingEntries.slice(duplicateIndex + 1)]
      } else {
        return existingEntries
      }
    },
    myArray
  )
```

Use `myArray` as the initial value of your new array, and compare the entries contained in your tempArray to check if you should add them or not.

Focus on immutability is a good practice and brings a lot of advantages. This post is explaining properly why you should focus on immutability : [What is immutability and why should I worry about it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622664/what-is-immutability-and-why-should-i-worry-about-it)